# space in style css in Angular-2+ animations

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-forms

https://angular.io/guide/animations in angular 4 animations in state style why prefix is not supported?

in this plunker

https://plnkr.co/edit/ALfIp5nfno2uxBgXEBST

when i am trying to add css style

```
 animation-delay: 2s;
```

in state style

```
 state('visible', style({ left: '0', transition: '650ms ease-in-out', })),
```

it is giving me an error (`TypeScript ':' expected. (TS1005)`)

so i wanted to add some css rule to support others browsers too like firefox (-moz prefix) but it is not accepting any prefixes)

any work-around or solutions?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: TypeScript ':' expected. (TS1005)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in guide

> Angular animations are built on top of the standard Web Animations API
>   and run natively on browsers that support it.
>
> For other browsers, a polyfill is required. Uncomment the
>   web-animations-js polyfill from the polyfills.ts file.

this is written so uncomment web-animations-js in polyfill.ts file and install it